# Troubleshooting a program with an arraylist, java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have created this code for an assignment in my school computer science class

```
public class Party {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int friends = scanner.nextInt();
    ArrayList <Integer> list  = new ArrayList<Integer>(friends);        

    for(int i = 0 ; i < friends ; i++){
        list.add(i + 1);
    }

    int rounds = scanner.nextInt();


    for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++) {

        int number = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int j = 0 ; j < list.size() ; i++) {

            if(j%number == 0){
                list.remove(j);
            }

        }

    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; i++){
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
}
```

The code is supposed to take a number than create an arraylist with values n, n+2, n+3 and so on until this number.
Than the program asks for a number x this will be the number of turns.
then the program asks for x number of numbers which it will use to take out the values with the indexes that are multiple of these numbers. for some reason it keeps on terminating when it's not done yet.
all help is appreciated!

Comment: Your `for j` suspiciously increments `i`. You should use a debugger to find out why your code is not behaving...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the **i++** by **j++** because in this case j < list.size() is always true

```
    for (int j = 0 ; j < list.size() ; i++)
```